# Automation in Azure web apps to import key vault certificate

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

Is there a way to automate the process of importing a key vault certificate within Azure app services?  I'm referring specifically to the option in the portal circled below.  I can't find anything in PowerShell or ARM Templates.

I found a way to do this as a one-time deployment via ARM templates, but that option does not rotate the certificate if it rotates in KV.  To my understanding the "import" functionality in circled below maintains the connection to KV and handles the rotation automatically.

If there's a way to automate this, it would be great, rather than having to go through the portal and click these buttons for each region I deploy each service to.

[image: Portal Screenshot]

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? I'm stuck on this too. All the ARM solutions I find for this are to use the certificate from KV Secret, not KV Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a web job that does this when a new version of certificate is created in KeyVault. According to the [blog](https://blog.atwork.at/post/Automate-SSL-certificates-updates-with-App-Services-and-Azure-Key-Vault), the web job that applies the new certificate runs once a day so you have to time your creation of new version of the certificate in KeyVault at least a day before the expiry so certificate gets renewed before the expiry.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to automate the initial import. Right now the only way I see is to manually click on the Import Key Vault Certificate button circled above.